# Generate java file from XML file without any API

Tags: java, xml, dynamic, xml-parsing

How can I generate Java file, means generate name of classes methods attributes, without using any API  from XML

my XML file : Source

```
<class name="person">

<Attribut type="int">Age</Attribut>
<Attribut type="String">Name</Attribut>
</class>
```

to java file:

```
 public class person {
    int age;
    String Name;
 }
```

Your help is very appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a `source` example which explains what you tried to do.

Comment: If you don't want to use any XML API (e.g. [Simple API for XML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html)) you would need to write the parser yourself. Why you want to do that? As you said you don't want to use JAXB. Why not using at least SAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to do it your own. You might have a look on this simplified example.

**Warnings first:**

- it lacks proper Exception handling
- it is build only to work with your proposed XML example

The sample code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class XMLStreamReaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlFileName = "source.xml";
        StringBuilder javaSource = transform(xmlFileName);
        System.out.println(javaSource);
    }

    static StringBuilder transform(String xmlFileName) throws
            FactoryConfigurationError, IOException, XMLStreamException {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader parser = null;
        StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFileName)) {
            parser = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
            while (parser.hasNext()) {
                switch (parser.getEventType()) {
                    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                        processStartElement(parser, source);
                        break;
                    case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                        processCharacters(parser, source);
                        break;

                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                        processEndElement(parser, source);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                parser.next();
            }
        } finally {
            if (parser != null) {
                parser.close();
            }
        }
        return source;
    }

    static void processEndElement(XMLStreamReader reader, StringBuilder sb) {
        String element = reader.getLocalName();
        if ("class".equals(element)) {
            sb.append("}");
        } else if ("Attribut".equals(element)) {
            sb.append(";\n");
        }
    }

    static void processCharacters(XMLStreamReader reader, StringBuilder sb) {
        if (!reader.isWhiteSpace()) {
            sb.append(" ").append(reader.getText());
        }
    }

    static void processStartElement(XMLStreamReader reader, StringBuilder sb) {
        String element = reader.getLocalName();
        if ("class".equals(element)) {
            sb.append("public class ")
                    .append(reader.getAttributeValue(0))
                    .append(" {\n");
        } else if ("Attribut".equals(element)) {
            sb.append("    ")
                    .append(reader.getAttributeValue(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `source.xml` contains

```
<class name="person">
<Attribut type="int">Age</Attribut>
<Attribut type="String">Name</Attribut>
</class>
```

the code prints

```
public class person {
    int Age;
    String Name;
}
```

The "only" thing left for you to do: implement all the missing parts. If this still contains "too much" XML API ... well ... write you own parser. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate java classes from `xsd or xml` file without using any java code or class file use jaxb https://jaxb.java.net/ or a exe file default provided by java located in jdk bin folder xjc.exe

documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html

Comment: This is wrong! JAXB can be used to generate Java code from *XML schema* documents, not from any XML.

Comment: Would be nice to see how `xjc` could build from the provided XML input the Java source.

Comment: but without api jaxb only java!