# Generate Java class from custom model

Tags: java, xml, api, dom

[Generate java file from XML file without any API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270490/generate-java-file-from-xml-file-without-any-api?newreg=1b64415f5e504695a7e481d4fe73d8df)

Hi, I would like to know if it's possible to generate a java class from existing model as illustrate in this picture below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB9rW.png)

Informations about the generated class will be found in a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity name="Balise1">
    <attribut name="a" type="List" basetypeid="1"/>
    <typedef type="List" basetypeid="2" id="1"/>
    <typedef type="String" id="2"/> 
</entity>
```

For exemple when I find the tagname "entity" I create a instance of MjEntity and so on. After iterating the XML file, I have just to generate my Java class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a costum XML format reader requires you to write your own generator.

There are formats that can generate Java classes from XML. Take a look at .XSD -> .java here..
[Generate Java classes from .XSD files...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686453/generate-java-classes-from-xsd-files)

Also, if you dont want entity relations in the class object, you can create an orm.xml (Object Relation Mapping) to define this. Take a look at
https://dzone.com/articles/persisting-entity-classes